# Adding month to date from input type date in angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular

I have two input fields inside my form:

```
<input type="date" [(ngModel)]="contractInception" name="contractInception">
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="contractLength" (blur)="calculateContractEnd()" name="contractLength" maxlength="2" max="72">
```

what i want is, that the user fills out the date, when the contract was signed and than he adds the amount of month the contract is running. Than, onBlur, when he leaves the `contractLength` field, i want the contractInception Date + the amount of month the user added. And i need that value in my field `<input type="date" [(ngModel)]="contractEnd" name="contractEnd" disabled>`.

So the contract end is nothing that the user has to fill out, it can be calculated by the information he entered but i don't know how. All the things i found here on Stack or on google are not working in angular 4.

These are my models:

```
  contractLength: Number;
  contractInception: Date;
  contractEnd: Date;
```

**example**:

The user enters 20.04.2018 into `contractInception` and 12 into `contractLength` than i want `contractEnd` to be 20.04.2019

Comment: I would recommend using something like `moment.js`

Comment: It's not exactly clear what is the problem - do you successfully calculate the end date but it does not show? Please add the code for `calculateContractEnd()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took me a moment to find out, but now the solution with moment.js looks like this:

```
calculateContractEnd() {
      let monthToAdd = this.contractLength.toString();
      let dateToCalc = moment(this.contractInception).add(monthToAdd, 'month'); 
      let newDate = dateToCalc.toDate(); 
      let newConvertedDate = newDate.toISOString() 
      let newOnlyDate = newConvertedDate.split('T')[0]; 
      this.contractEnd = newOnlyDate; 
  }
```

problem was to get a value which can be parsed back into the value field from an `<input type="date">` but with that solution, its working!